# Ruby hash of arrays remove first element from array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of arrays `arr = [["U6342", "2015-01-12", "Account"],other similar arrays]`

then i group it by first element

```
arr.group_by(&:first)
 => {"U6342"=>[["U6342", "2015-01-12", "Account"],other similar arrays]]
```

But i want to remove first element from all of arrays and get

```
 => {"U6342"=>[[ "2015-01-12", "Account"],other similar arrays]]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible... But I guess that you're expecting another answer. Show what you tried, and what problem you're facing, then people will be able to help you.

Comment: You could improve your question by including a complete example. Here I'd suggest that `arr` contain four or five arrays. That way, all the answers will use that example. Aside from that, I don't understand why your question has been downvoted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". As is, you've asked a very broad question, so you get broad answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One might [`shift`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-shift) a required element inplace.

```
arr.group_by &:shift
```

Whether you do not want to modify an original array:

```
arr.map(&:dup).group_by &:shift
```

Comment: awesome, just awesome!

Comment: `shift` also modify "original" array. Just for info;)

Comment: @mudasobwa no problem, but this your update also modify "original" bcs. `dup` method duplicate only first level of array :) use this `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(arr)).group_by &:shift`

Comment: @LukasBaliak indeed, but `Marshal` is an overkill here. Pls see an update.

Comment: @mudasobwa yes, `Marshal` is overkil in this case:) And yes, you can do it with `map(&:dup)`. nice work ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think some of the other answerers are overthinking it:

```
arr = [ ["U6342", "2015-01-12", "Account"],
        ["U1234", "2015-02-12", "Foo"],
        ["U6342", "2015-03-12", "Bar"],
        ["U1234", "2015-04-12", "Qux"] ]

arr.group_by(&:shift)
# => { "U6342" => [ [ "2015-01-12", "Account" ],
#                   [ "2015-03-12", "Bar"     ] ],
#      "U1234" => [ [ "2015-02-12", "Foo"     ],
#                   [ "2015-04-12", "Qux"     ] ]
#    }
```

`Array#shift` removes the first element from the array and returns it. `arr.group_by(&:shift)` removes the first element from each element in `arr` and groups by it.

Comment: Excelllent! You posted shortly after @mudasobwa (the time it took to add your example), but close enough that I'd call it a tie, so leave your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
arr = [["U6342", "2015-01-12", "Account"], ["U6343", "2015-02-12", "Bank"]]

Hash[arr.map{|ar| [ar.first, ar[1..-1]]}]
# => {"U6342"=>["2015-01-12", "Account"], "U6343"=>["2015-02-12", "Bank"]}
```

or with "modify" the orginal `arr` variable

```
Hash[arr.map{|ar| [ar.shift, ar]}]
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `group_by` to group-by:

```
arr = [["dog", "named", "Bert"],
       ["cat", "named", "Boots"],
       ["dog", "named", "Hank"],
       ["pig", "named", "Porky"],
       ["cat", "named", "Tiger"]]

arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }) { |(f,*a),h| h[f] << a }
  # => {"dog"=>[["named", "Bert"], ["named", "Hank"]],
  #     "cat"=>[["named", "Boots"], ["named", "Tiger"]],
  #     "pig"=>[["named", "Porky"]]}
```

Note this doesn't mutate `arr`.